# Why is my my prompt for a user name failing while trying to create a system to generate a random code with user initials?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a script that can be run in a browser by our school district's secretaries. Basically they will put in a new student or new hires name and get a 8 digit output, a six digit random number and the users initials added at the end. They will be copying this into one of our systems and the unique code will kickstart automatic account creation. We have the account creation set and working, but are having a hard time getting the unique code. I have not included the random number portion of the script as my only problem lies with prompting for the user's name and extracting the initials.

```
function ID() {
    var userName = prompt("Please enter your name", "<User Name>");
}

function getInitials(name) {
  let initials = "";
  let waitingForSpace = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (!waitingForSpace) {
      initials += name[i];
      waitingForSpace = true;
    }

    if (name[i] === " ") {
      waitingForSpace = false;
    }
  }

  return initials;
}
console.log(getInitials(userName));
```

I think I should get a prompt for User Name, which is stored as userName. That is then used to getInitials. however when I try and run Node Initials.js I get...

> ReferenceError: userName is not defined
>       at Object. (/Users/dross/Documents/UserID/Initials.js:22:25)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

Comment: The first place I would start would be to look at why you have a function and a variable both named `userName`

Comment: You have missing bracket `}` at the end.

Comment: You have **`function userName() { ... }`** which means you should call it with **braces**: `console.log(getInitials(userName()));`  And then it will still only work if the function actually *return*-s something (it doesn't seem to) + the function needs to have a closing `}`.

Comment: Changed the function name to ID, but adding a bracket now just gives me userName is not defined error, no prompt still for the user's name.

Comment: Please post your edit. (Update the code in question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing `}` in your code. You can change your code to something like this:

```js
function getUserName() {
  var userName = prompt("Please enter your name", "<User Name>");
  return userName; // return the entered name
}

function getInitials(name) {
  let initials = "";
  let waitingForSpace = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (!waitingForSpace) {
      initials += name[i];
      waitingForSpace = true;
    }

    if (name[i] === " ") {
      waitingForSpace = false;
    }
  }

  return initials;
}

var name = getUserName(); // returns the name entered
console.log(getInitials(name));
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done minimal JS work (but more than any of the other tech) this was a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

In your original post, you were actually delivering the whole function as closure, therefore the inner 'username' function was available on the outside. Btw., I don't think that a '{' was missing.

Now, in your revised code, you have 'username' as local variable as it is no longer assigned a 'function'. Therefore, it is now 'not defined' on the outside.

I think you should pay attention to the comment of Peter B, stating that you have to call the (original) function as
`console.log(getInitials(userName()));`